# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.BIOMETRIC_ENROLL (has extras) }

Tags: android

I am implementing fingerprint authentication on my app. If the user hasn't set up a fingerprint on his device. I am trying to open system settings for enrolling fingerprints. According to documentation(https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth), this is the code for opening the setting activity for enrolling fingerprint.

```
 final Intent enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
    enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
            BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
    startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

I have tested the app on two devices. In Samsung, the code is working. But in an Asus device, it is not working.

Comment: Which ASUS device are you testing on and which Android version is it running?

Comment: I'm having the same error on Pixel 2 emulator on SDK 23

Answer (score 1):

As in the Google documentation ["ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL) added at API 30, that's what causes your app to crash